# Маршрут в laravel не регестрирует

Tags: laravel

```
Route::post('/kalendar', 'CalendarController@send')->name('kalendar.send');;
Route::get('/kalendar', 'CalendarController@index')->name('kalendar.index');;
Route::post('/kalendar', 'CalendarController@store')->name('kalendar.store');
```

Команда `php artisan route:list` выдает только 2 маршрута кроме send

Как правильно его зарегистрировать ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно не создавать 2 одинаковых маршрута, ваш маршрут store перезаписал send

```
Route::post('/kalendar-send', 'CalendarController@send')->name('kalendar.send');;
Route::post('/kalendar-store', 'CalendarController@store')->name('kalendar.store');
```

Comment: Подскажите как тогда организовать маршруты если есть 2 формы, одна обращается к методу store а другая к send ?

Comment: Создать 2 маршрута - это же очевидно

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста на примере, в Laravel не так давно...

Comment: @АлексейМарченко добавил в ответ

Comment: @Alpha спасибо!